# Quickly find module to import based on Class name in python

Tags: python, import, module, pyside2

I am learning and playing with Python and Pyside2 (wrapper of QT5).

I am asking about PySide2 but a possible answer could help me with every package.

Basically I am following a tutorial in which I read a portion of code that I am reporting here:

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
pixmap = QPixmap(":/splash.png")
splash = QSplashScreen(pixmap)
splash.show()
app.processEvents()
window = QMainWindow()
window.show()
splash.finish(window)
```

Since I am a beginner and the tutorial doesn't mention which module I have to import in order to be able to use the QSplashScreen, I am constantly wasting time asking Google on which module I have to import in order to use some method or Class, in this case QSplashScreen.

for example, in order to use a QLabel in my code I have to type

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QLabel
```

My understanding is that QLabel is "inside" QtWidgets which in turn are "inside" PySide2.

Now my question is if there exist something within Python in such a way that I could do (in a REPL)

```
import magic
magic.findInTheFollowingPackage("PySide2").somethingINeed("QLabel")
>>> PySide2.QtWidgets # output
```

Then I could get the answer for

```
magic.findInThisPackage("PySide2").somethingINeed("QSplashScreen")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *

def get_import_of(cls):
    print('from', cls.__module__, 'import', cls.__name__)
```

To print the import statement for any class.

```
>>> get_import_of(QSplashScreen)
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QSplashScreen

>>> get_import_of(QPixmap)
from PySide2.QtGui import QPixmap
```

Can extend the function to support multiple arguments:

```
def get_import_of(*args):
    d = {cls.__module__: [] for cls in args}
    for cls in args:
        d[cls.__module__].append(cls.__name__)
    print('\n'.join(f'from {k} import ' + ', '.join(v) for k, v in d.items()))


>>> get_import_of(QSplashScreen, QPixmap, QLabel, QTimer)
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QSplashScreen, QLabel
from PySide2.QtGui import QPixmap
from PySide2.QtCore import QTimer
```

Or just type class name into the interactive shell.

```
>>> QSplashScreen
<class 'PySide2.QtWidgets.QSplashScreen'>
```